# Moving Logo On The Left And On The Same Line

Tags: css

I would like to move the logo to the left of site title and description. I have Googled CSS tweaks to reposition the logo but it didn't work. I have little to no knowledge about CSS.

Is there anyone who can help me please? The site is www.cebubibleseminary.com

Comment: Show what you have tried please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to stack overflow.
I hope this helps

**CSS fix**

```
.site-intro .avatar {
width: 104px;
float: inherit;
}
```

this is how it will look after
[image]

Comment: @ Beep. Thank you so much for your help. Is there any way we can have the logo a little bit closer to the first letter (C ) though? And the height used to be around 400px but now it went down to around 200px which is understandable since we removed the logo there. Is there any way as well we can maintain the height?

Comment: Of course, it is simple just alter the css. I am glade I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that headers automatically create new lines. This website did something similar:

palyrobotics.com

Make the header with the style "display:inline;". See below for an example:

```
<img src="/assets/img/logos/main_logo.png" width="100" height="50">
<div class="show-for-small-only">
  <h2 style="display:inline; margin-left:-10px;">Paly Robotics</h2>
</div>
```

You would do:

```
<a href="http://www.cebubibleseminary.com/" title="Cebu Bible Seminary Inc." rel="home" class="site-intro">
  <img alt="Cebu Bible Seminary Inc." src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/cc3b29587548d89dfb16b15223a18995?s=256&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D256&amp;r=G" class="avatar avatar-256 photo" height="256" width="256">
  <h1 class="site-title" style="display:inline;">Cebu Bible Seminary Inc.</h1>
  <h2 class="site-description"></h2>
</a>
```

This should work. LMK if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you have the tags wrong. This should be a CSS question.

To solve your problem just put the content in 2 divs. Apply the style property float left and float right for example. If you want them aligned use the attribute width. An example:

```
<div style="float:left; width:300px;">
  <img alt="Cebu Bible Seminary Inc." src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/cc3b29587548d89dfb16b15223a18995?s=256&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D256&amp;r=G" class="avatar avatar-256 photo" height="256" width="256">
</div>
<div style="float:right"; width:800px;>         
  <h1 class="site-title">Cebu Bible Seminary Inc.</h1>
  <h2 class="site-description"></h2>
</div>
```